# Can We add hash(#) after query params(with ?) in Angular 4/6 routing?

Tags: angular, angular6

Whenever I use HashLocationStategy and useHas:true, hash gets added after base url, however I need hash to be added after query params.

I need as follows:

> localhost:4200/?param1=param1val&param2=param2val/#search
>
> localhost:4200/?param1=param1val&param2=param2val/#about

However right now it happens as follows

> localhost:4200/#search?param1=param1val&param2=param2val
>
> localhost:4200/#about?param1=param1val&param2=param2val

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the hash in the params with %23.
The Percent Encoding should work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding